# setRGB fail after using ColorConvertOp in java

Tags: java

im trying to use this method to covert my image to grayscale.

```
private void GSActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        BufferedImage temp = showing; //showing is a varible that store my temp img.
        int[][] data = getData(temp); // getData() give me a 2d array that has images     coordinate and default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB).

        ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
        ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(cs, null);
        temp = op.filter(temp, null);

        BufferedImage newImage = temp;
        picDisplay.setIcon(new ImageIcon(newImage));
        picDisplay.updateUI();
        showing = newImage;
}
```

after this method my img change to grayscale, that is good, but when i use another method like flipping the img, it gives me a lot of error:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.getDataElements(ComponentColorModel.java:1555)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.setRGB(BufferedImage.java:988)
    at photoshop.GUI.VFActionPerformed(GUI.java:213)
    at photoshop.GUI.access$700(GUI.java:13)
    at photoshop.GUI$8.actionPerformed(GUI.java:113)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)`

Comment: [This](http://xkcd.com/979/) is totally me right now >.<